# vb.net using a custom file to save different types of data

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, filesystems, entity-framework-5

I'm brushing up on my VB.NET skills for a future project I will be working on.  This application will be very data intensive, requiring 20+ data tables, user supplied images, and possibly even short audio/video files.

I want to be able to save all of this information into a single, external file, so that the user can share what they create with the world.

Ideally, I would like all the text based data to be stored in a database format that I can easily work with, preferably via the entity framework.

Pretty much all the information I'm finding relates to only saving a single text/XML file, and that will not really work for me.  Can anyone point me in the proper direction, or suggest a method that will let me save the data?

I'm working inside Visual Studio 2012 Pro, with a Visual Basic Windows Form Application.  Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: Why will saving as text or XML not work for you?

Comment: There will be many files, some of them images, audio, and video, in addition to some sort of database formatted information.

Comment: So basically a dynamic zipfile? That should suit your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll expand my comment to an answer instead.

As previously mentioned this sounds like a zip file. In this you can:

Have a file called databasetables.txt or whatever containing the database tables.
You can have Audio, Video, Images etc in respective folders. This way when you open your file you can just load all files in the Audio folder to get the expected files.

You can have information stored in xmlfiles.

Endless posibilities...

Just keep in mind that you might want to load all this only into the memory of the computer so you dont extract it onto the hard drive.

And you dont have to save the file as .zip to open it as .zip, just select your own cool suffix which will look neat :)

Comment: Thank you, this sounds like it will work exactly as I want it to.  I'd tried looking for info on zip files, but until reading your answer my google-fu wasn't providing the correct answers, I think I have it figured out now though.